# Reselect always re rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reselect

I'm trying to add reselect to my react code but it seems to be always rerendering.

Everytime I change my state the console prints "testing" even though the input-selector is not changing. I created a simple test to show you guys whats happening.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

window.testObject = {'x': '5'}
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {

  const test = state => {return window.testObject}
  const getTest = createSelector(test, (t)=> console.log('testing'))

  return {
      test: getTest(state),
  }
}


export default const TestContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(TestBase)
```

What am I doing wrong?? I keep re reading the documentation and from what I can tell the console.log should not be running after the first time since the input-selector is not changing. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: I don't think `reselect` performs a deep comparison. Every time `getTest` is called, a new object is returned.

Comment: You are correct, should of realized that haha. I'm going to try making the object global and see if it works :)

Comment: I updated the example to use a global object to no effect. It still prints "testing" in the same way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling the `createSelector` every time it re-renders

move the `createSelector` outside of the mapStateToProps

```
const getTest = createSelector(...)

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  test: getTest(state),
})

export default const TestContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(TestBase)
```

Comment: You just blew my mind. Thank you I'm going to try this right now!!

Comment: what is the usage of reselect? What is the intent of the middleware?

Comment: Its so that if you have an calculation intensive function you recalculate only when the inputs to the selector change, instead of on every render. It doesn't have anything to do with middleware, you can use it separate from react/redux.

Comment: @DaxChen it's also good to consider moving your selectors into a centralized module of sorts.  Promotes reuse. :)

Comment: You saved my day!